# Generic class with Id c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am not sure if this is possible, but I have started a new project and I am trying to clean up the way I work with the **DbContext**. I am trying to do this by using generics.
The first part is easy. I create a **Repository** class like this:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbEntitySet;

    public Repository(InteractiveChoicesContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbEntitySet = dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the entities
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="includes">Option includes for eager loading</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IQueryable<T> List(params string[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbEntitySet;
        foreach (var include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
        return query;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public void Create(T model) => _dbEntitySet.Add(model);

    /// <summary>
    ///     Updates an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public void Update(T model) => _dbEntitySet.Update(model);

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    public void Remove(T model) => _dbContext.Entry<T>(model).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    /// <summary>
    /// Saves the database context changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Now I want to create a generic **Service** class that can use all the CRUD methods. I tried to create it like this:

```
public class Service<T> : Service<T, int> where T : class
{
    public Service(InteractiveChoicesContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}

public class Service<T, TKey>: Repository<T> where T: class
{
    public Service(InteractiveChoicesContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ListAsync() => await List().ToListAsync();
    public virtual async Task<T> GetAsync(TKey id) => await List().SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
    public virtual async Task<T> CreateAsync(T model)
    {
        Create(model);
        await SaveChangesAsync();
        return model;
    }
    public virtual async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T model)
    {
        Update(model);
        await SaveChangesAsync();
        return model;
    }
    public virtual async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(TKey id)
    {
        var model = await GetAsync(id);
        Remove(model);
        await SaveChangesAsync();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am using **TKey** to specify the primitive type, but the issue is with the **GetAsync** method. Obviously it doesn't know what the object is at this point, so it will not compile. I get this error:

'T' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Now I know this is because I haven't said what **T** is.
Looking at how **IdentityFramework** handle this, they use **IUser**, I could do the same, but it would mean ALL my entities would have to implement this interface.
If I created an interface like this:

```
public interface IEntity<out TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; }
}
```

And then updated all my entities to implement the interface like this:

```
public class Question : IEntity<int>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(100)] public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool MultipleChoice { get; set; }

    public OutcomeGroup Group { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

That seems to work. I guess I only have one question. 
Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: If your code works and you're just asking if this is the "best" way, then the question probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com (though better check with their rules first)

Comment: Yes, implementing interface to access to specific properties of generic-typed variable is usually the best way. Note that EF `DbSet` has `Find` (and `FindAsync`) method which accepts array of objects representing entity primary keys, which can be used in your case instead of `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that :)

Comment: So if your table has a million records, and you plan to fetch one using GetAsync, your first get all million records to local memory and then throw them all away except one? Consider keeping it IQueryable as long as possible. Let your caller decide when to execute your queries, so he can concatenate IQueryable extensions efficiently

Comment: I keep it IQueryable until it reaches the API endpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have your entities like this :

```
public interface IEntity<out TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; }
}

public class Question<TPrimaryKey> : IEntity<int>
{
     public TPrimaryKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

then your repository like this :

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> where TEntity: IEntity<TPrimaryKey>
{
    protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbEntitySet;

    public Repository(InteractiveChoicesContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbEntitySet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

and in my opinion, this is the best way to do it "Generic".

Comment: `DbSet<T>` what is `T` ? This won't compile. It should be `TEntity` I think.

Comment: @Fabjan yes should be TEntity.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need some way to point towards the ID / key property.

Some ideas to explore:

- As you already wrote, create an interface which all your entities will implement which denotes the Id property
- (Bonus) You can have a base entity class which implements the above interface AND has the required EF annotations (`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`) to make things easier
- Use reflection to search for the Id property by name in your `GetAsync` method (obviously the code wouldn't be as simple as it is now)
- Create a custom or use an existing attribute (for example, the [`KeyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)) and add it to your entities to mark the Id property and use reflection as with the idea before to find the property

Of all of these solutions, I'd go for the first or second one as those seem to be most "clear". If you decide to go for reflection, then I'd go for the second one (where you have a key-defining attribute) - but this still forces you to go through all your entities and make changes. If you have a LOT of entities, then perhaps the text-based property search might be the fastest - but obviously any entity which doesn't have a property named "Id" will cause issues.

Obviously YMMV depending on what you actually want to accomplish. Note that you can try and combine the reflection solutions (find by name, if not found search by key attribute).

Also remember that while reflection is a powerful tool, it has a performance impact.