# Entity Framework Generic Method do not accept Contains Method

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, entity-framework-6, contains

I have a parent class and some children classes like this:

```
 public class TableParent
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Parent_id{ get; set; }

    }

     public class T1
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Parent_id{ get; set; }
       public int id{ get; set; }
    }

     public class T2
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Parent_id{ get; set; }
      public int id{ get; set; }
    }

     public class T3
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Parent_id{ get; set; }
      public int id{ get; set; }
    }
```

I have a `list<int>` with selected Parent_id from table `tableParent`. I need to select from T1, T2, T3 those records with Parent_id contained in the List.

I can do a Method for each table like this:

```
 public static async Task RunPromotionAddresId(List<int> promociones)
        {
            string ConnexionOrigen = "datasource..."

            List<T2> listaPromos = new List<T2>();
            using (var db = new MigrateModel(ConnexionOrigen))
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                listaPromos = db.t2.Where(r => promociones.Contains(r.Parent_Id)).ToList();
            }

        }
```

And it works fine. I want to do a Generic Method to be called three times:

```
 public static async Task GetFromDatabase<T>(List<int> promociones) where T : class
        {
            string ConnexionOrigen = "datasource"

            List<T> listaPromos = new List<T>();
            using (var db = new MigrateModel(ConnexionOrigen))
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                listaPromos = db.Set<T>().Where(r => promociones.Contains(r.Parent_id)).ToList();

            }

        }
```

But got an error in .`Contains(r.Parent_id)`:

> T does not have a definition for Parent_id

How can I use `Contains Method` with generics. Or how can I replace it?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511499/generic-class-with-id-c-sharp

Comment: Read [ask] and show what you have tried. Looks like you need an interface `IChild` with an  `int Parent_id` property, and constrain your generic method to that.

Comment: CodeCaster, thanks,I create a interface with that Parent_id... what do you mean with "constrain your generic method"? Thanks..

Comment: @Diego Google for `c# constrain your generic method`.

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks.... It works now...